# What is this tree from Thailand with medicinal properties?

Tags: identification, trees

Please help me identify a tree located near Si Sa Ket Thailand. The bark is used as a medicine. Used by local traditional healers. Unfortunately they do not know the name of the tree. Many things are passed down in a verbal tribal knowledge format. The tree is not common. We travel to a remote area near the Cambodian border to obtain a very small strip of bark. I enclosed a picture of leaves and bark.

[image]

Comment: They would have their own name for the tree for sure, even if its not botanically correct. Also, precisely what medical purpose is the bark used for?

Comment: Looks like a legume  - impossible to tell exactly what, though, without some more detail.

Comment: Well this is closed but for what it's worth, there's a good chance this is Cassia alata. It's a common Asian remedy for parasites, etc.